# Select item type and its base type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple table :

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(item INT, itemType INT  )

insert INTO @t SELECT 1000,0
insert INTO @t SELECT 1000,3
insert INTO @t SELECT 1000,5
insert INTO @t SELECT 1000,6
insert INTO @t SELECT 2000,0
insert INTO @t SELECT 2000,3
insert INTO @t SELECT 2000,5
insert INTO @t SELECT 2000,6
insert INTO @t SELECT 3000,0
insert INTO @t SELECT 3000,10
insert INTO @t SELECT 4000,11
```

I want to select all items where `itemtype = 3` but *if there is a row* , provide also its base `itemtype` (*if it exists*) which is `itemType = 0`.

For example :

- for itemType = 3

  `1000,0` should be provided  --why ? because table also has 1000 + itemType 0
  `1000,3` should be provided  --why ? because we looked for itemType=3
  `2000,0` should be provided  --why ? because table has found 2000,3 and this 2000 also has itemType=0
  `2000,3` should be provided  --why ? because we looked for itemType=3
- for itemType = 10

  `3000,0` should be provided   --why ? because table has found 3000,10 and this 3000 also has itemType=0
  `3000,10` should be provided  --why ? because we looked for itemType=10
- for itemType = 11

  `4000,11` should be provided   --why ? because we looked for itemType=11 ( notice , there isn't itemType 0  , so only itself).

I started doing  :

```
;with cte as(
             SELECT * FROM @t  
            )
select * from cte where itemType=3
```

In summary, if the `itemType` is found, provide itself + its zero type (if exists), and also for his siblings ( sample(#1) )

<strike>But I can't do `union`  here cause CTE is not recognized there...</strike> rubbish. it is possible.

How can I solve it ?

[SQL ONLINE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/93494)

Comment: @JW. Ive also added bold summary.( if it helps)

Comment: @JW. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efb1c/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid evaluating the `itemType = 3` query twice you can self outer join then use `CROSS APPLY ... VALUES` to `UNPIVOT`

```
DECLARE @itemType INT = 3;

WITH T(item1, itemType1, item2, itemType2 )
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   @t T1
                LEFT JOIN @t T2
                  ON T1.item = T2.item
                     AND T2.itemType = 0
                     AND T1.itemType <> 0
         WHERE  T1.itemType = @itemType) 
SELECT item,
       itemType
FROM   T
       CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (item1, itemType1),
                            (item2, itemType2) ) v(item, itemType) 
WHERE item IS NOT NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2228e/10)

**Execution Plans**

[image: Plans]

Comment: is it possible to eliminate the duplicates when `T1.itemType = 0` ?

Comment: superb. nothing less nothing more.

Comment: I know the cross apply as a row multiplier  , but never heard about this syntax of `values(...)`...

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH recordList
AS
(
  SELECT item, itemType
  FROM   SampleTable
  WHERE  itemType = 11 -- change here
)
SELECT item, itemType FROM recordList
UNION
SELECT a.item, a.itemType
FROM   SampleTable a
       INNER JOIN recordList b
          ON a.item = b.item
WHERE  a.itemtype = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e99da/7)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*using `IN` clause for multiple values*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e99da/8)

Comment: @RoyiNamir i'm not using `CROSS APPLY`, have you seen the link on fiddle? `:D`

Comment: WTF ? Why was I thinking that i can't access CTE after union all ? I was 100 % sure I cant access it after first usage ...and...union all...

Comment: before couple of days ago i pasted this photo http://i.stack.imgur.com/hYhOk.jpg thats why I remember I cant

Comment: @RoyiNamir hmmm. but it's working on the fiddle right? let me check again.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - You don't have a `FROM` clause where it "goes bang" in your screeenshot.

Comment: @MartinSmith I looked at your uploaded image. How do you compare the cost (*I mean which one is efficient*)? Example `40 - 10 - 50` vs `30 - 30 - 40`.

Comment: @JW. The first one is 15% of the cost of the batch and the second one 85% so SQL Server estimates the second one is 5 or 6 times more  expensive. These units are just based on estimates though and the various SQL Server costing assumptions so shouldn't be taken too literally. But I would expect the `outer join .. unpivot` to be better than the `select union join` as that one evaluates `recordList` twice.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks! The query is not as efficient as your because of the `union` right? I'll be deleting this one `:D`

Comment: @JW. he is actually wrote both quries in the same window  , one after another and you can see how sql divided the work to be done and hence we can assume the first query is faster.

Comment: @JW. dont delete. it is another way of doing it. other people might learn from it :-)

Comment: @JW. The `UNION` and also because it has 3 scan operators for `@t` rather than two for the outer join.

Comment: @MartinSmith why 3 ? `SELECT item, itemType FROM recordList` and `INNER JOIN recordList`...no?  ( I counted 2)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - The inner join is a self join so is 2 scans. Plus the other one above the union. You can count them in the graphical plan.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @findtype INT = 3;

WITH results AS
(
  SELECT t.item, @findtype
  FROM   @t t
  WHERE  t.itemType = @findtype
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.item, 0
  FROM   @t t
         INNER JOIN results r on r.item = t.item
  WHERE  t.itemType = 0
)
SELECT * 
FROM results;
```